# C# OLEDBConnection to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

I am copying an Excel sheet into a Datatable as such:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

            command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [working sheet$]", oleDBConnection);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

Is there a similar method where I can just simply copy the datatable back to an Excel sheet?  The examples I keep finding are copying cell by cell, but this can be noticably slow with large data sets.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating the command twice?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`DataAdapter.Update` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.update.aspx), which applies any changes made in the DataTable to the database (or spreadsheet, in this case)

Comment: Excellent, I knew there should be something just as simple.  Thanks.

Comment: Would you know what the update command for this would be?  I basically just want to commit any new updates to the Excel sheet.  But I cannot find an example of the appropriate update command on Google.  Thanks.

Comment: Use OleDbCommandBuilder.  It would be a regular `UPDATE` statement

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know much about OleDB with Excel, but since you mentioned a Database, I assume this runs on a server? Microsoft actually does not recomment running Excel on a server.

I would use OpenXML for tasks like this. It's a bit more complicated, but it's save and stable.

Comment: He's not running Excel; there's nothing wrong with using OleDB on a server.  Also, there is no reason to assume he's on a server.