# C# OleDBConnection Excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Following on from this question [C# OLEDBConnection to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648308/c-oledbconnection-to-excel)

I am having issues with using OLEdbCommandBuilder.
I have this code:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

            command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [working sheet$]", oleDBConnection);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

            OleDbCommandBuilder c = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

            //arbitrary changed datatable
            dt.Rows[2][3] = "dfd";

            c.GetUpdateCommand();

            dataAdapter.Update(dt);

            oleDBConnection.Close();
```

However when I run it, I get this error:

```
Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.
```

How can I update the Excel sheet with the updated row/cell information?  I've never had to deal with Excel in such a way before.

I've googled the error but cannot find anything that meets my exact requirements.

Thanks,

Darren.

Answer (score 1):

You can only update if the adapter knows the unique primary key of the excel-database-table. You can add an id-column as first column in excel and make it the primary key and continue like this

```
      ...
      dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
      ...
      System.Data.DataColumn pkCol = dt.Columns[0]; // something like dt.Columns["Id"]
      pkCol.Unique = true;
      dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {pkCol };
      ...
      OleDbCommandBuilder c = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
      ...
```

Comment: As a FYI here is a Microsoft KB about the issue that explains why this code is needed.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316756

Comment: And another MS [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/10/29/how-to-update-an-excel-worksheet-using-dataset-and-the-oledbdataadapter.aspx) with examples

Comment: This still doesn't work - I get the same error? I have added an ID column to the Excel sheet, that has sequential ID's and are unique, and used the code above?  Bugger!